# JAVA EE - Interfaz no encontrada al acceder a EJB en el servidor desde un cliente

Tags: java, maven, ejb

Tengo un proyecto en Java ee con Maven, dicha aplicación tiene un EJB con su correspondiente interfaz remota, estos componentes están deployados en un servidor Glassfish.

Por otra parte tengo otro proyecto también en Maven que ahce de cliente, solicitando mediante JNDI la instancia del EJB que implementa la interfaz remota, el problema es que en la llamada de JNDI se produce una excepción por no encontrar la interfaz mencionada.

Interfaz remota

```
package esotelo.sgsv.ejb.service;

import esotelo.sgsv.ejb.entity.Usuario;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface ISeguridadService {
    public int login(String pUsername, String pPassword);
    public int altaUsuario(Usuario pUsuario);
    public int actualizarContrasena(int pIdUsuario, String pPwd);
}
```

EJB

```
@Stateless
public class SeguridadServiceImpl implements ISeguridadService{
.............
```

Cliente

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try{
        Context jndi;
        ISeguridadService seguridadService;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");

        // optional. Default localhost. Aqui se cambia la IP del servidor donde esta Glassfish
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

        jndi = new InitialContext(props);
        seguridadService = (ISeguridadService) jndi.lookup("java:global/SGSV/SeguridadServiceImpl!esotelo.sgsv.ejb.service.ISeguridadService");
        int resultado = seguridadService.login("ESOTELO", "BARBA8888");
        System.out.println("resultado: " + resultado);
    }catch(NamingException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el momento que se ejecuta jndi.lookup ... se genera la siguiente excepción:

javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfaceesotelo.sgsv.ejb.service.ISeguridadService [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: esotelo.sgsv.ejb.service.ISeguridadService]

...

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: esotelo.sgsv.ejb.service.ISeguridadService

Cabe destacar que el servidor de glassfish esta en la misma pc que el proyecto cliente y como verán el package del EJB como de la interfaz son correctos en la llamada JNDI, agradeszco toda ayuda que me puedan brindar